# How can I avoid showing html code in a UI-grid cell with Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

The field that I am passing to the ui-grid is an html fragment. like this:

```
<span style="color:BLACK; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;" onclick="openForm(154,68962)">PENDING</span>
```

And the ui-grid is showing the html code inside the cell. I want to show not the html but the span with the on-click event working. I tried assigning this to the ui-grid field `{{ COL_FIELD }}` like this but it did not work:

```
{ displayName: 'Form Status', field: 'FormStatus', headerCellClass: 'center', width: '80', enableColumnMenu: false, cellClass: 'text-center', cellTooltip: true, cellTemplate: {{COL_FIELD}} },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Could try `cellTemplate` in UI Grid 
eg code,

```
var linkCellTemplate = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">' + '<a href="{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}">Visible text</a>' + '</div>';
```

Defined the `var linkCellTemplate` inside your Controller and point out in `$scope.gridoptions` like

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
columnDefs: [{
                'field':'link',
                'cellTemplate':linkCellTemplate
            }]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The field contains text, and even if this text is a valid html code, it will remain text. What you are trying to get is to convert text to html element 'on the fly'. Angular has a support for this using [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). It does sanitation of the html and might drop some parts of it. If this is a problem, have a look at [this great article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/10/a-journey-with-trusted-html-in-angularjs.aspx) for an explanation of how to bypass it.

I assume that this will change your config a bit:

```
.... cellTemplate: <div ng-bind-html="{{COL_FIELD}}"></div>
```

If you got all this to display property, you might find that your handler (is it defined on the scope?) is not triggered/found. If this is the case, you might have to use ui-grid's appScope.